# Share files between applications in iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have a 'light'/'free' application and a full version of this app.
I want to make sure that if a user has the free version and purchases the full version,
then they will get a message asking if they want to merge the state of the free app into the full one.

Can this be done using iCloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires that both applications use the same Team ID.  As long as they are setup with this same Team ID in the entitlements, they can share content.

[Reference document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/EnablingiCloud/EnablingiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH2-SW1)

Comment: I just asked a question similar to this, pertaining to the primary app and whether or not it is required.  That might be related to this in that what if the user never installs the free version and wants to share data?  What if that's the primary app?  Does that matter?